# How to create optional input for scanf in C?

Tags: c

I need to create some form of input where the user can type in various instructions. It is optional whether they append a value such as: **'ADD1**'. Add is the instruction, 1 is the value. If no value is appended instructions will be carried out where no value is required such as **'END'** for looping. Let's say the user does not enter a value, how do i make this possible so that 'val' is optional? If no value is appended scanf should just attatch the string input to **'instr'** and ignore **'val'**.

Sample:

```
Scanf("%s %d", instr, val);
```

Comment: `retVal=scanf("%[A-Z] %d", instr, &val);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the approach to problems like that is to use `scanf` to get in the whole string, and then parse it yourself when it is in memory:

```
char cmdline[100];
scanf("%99s", cmdline);
if (strstr(cmdline, "ADD") == cmdline) {
    ... Get an int from cmdline buffer starting at position 3
} else if (strstr(cmdline, "END") == cmdline) {
    ... Don't get anything
}
```